# How to change specific key color in custom keyboard view?

Tags: android, xml

I am creating a POS-based application when onscreen keyboard is created using keyboard view. But every key is black colour. I am able to change the complete keyboard background in keyboard view tag.

But that is not what i need! I am attaching a image below:

[image]

When user press "QTY" button the background of that button should turn to green or any other colour. when user press "Price" the colour of "QTY" should back to previous state and "Price" key should turn Green.

I searched a lot but never find a solution for this.  I need a solution to change the colour of the specific key

my XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="11%p"
    android:keyHeight="8.5%p" >

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1"    android:keyLabel="1" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="2"    android:keyLabel="2" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="3"    android:keyLabel="3" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="-1"    android:keyLabel="QTY" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="4"    android:keyLabel="4" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="5"    android:keyLabel="5" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="6"    android:keyLabel="6" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="-2"   android:keyLabel="DIS" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="7"    android:keyLabel="7" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="8"    android:keyLabel="8" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="9"    android:keyLabel="9" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="-3"   android:keyLabel="Price" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-4"    android:keyLabel="." android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="0"    android:keyLabel="0" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="100"  android:keyLabel="PAY"  android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5"   android:keyIcon="@drawable/back" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Comment: Seems like you could do that with sticky keys. I've not done an IME, but from a quick look through the source and sample, you would add `android:isSticky="true"` to those two `Key`s. To customize the color, create your own drawable based on [this platform drawable](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_keyboard_key.xml). Then set that as the `keyBackground` value on your `style` whose `parent` is [`Widget.KeyboardView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#741),

Comment: ...and set that `style` as the [`keyboardViewStyle`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#309) in your app's theme.

Comment: @MikeM. Can you please post a sample code

Comment: Um, maybe? I'll have to make sure it works, first. It'll be a little bit before I get to it, but I'll let you know.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok, please. I am struggling to make it work

Comment: OK, I did some tests, and it's a little simpler than I thought, since I didn't realize that you have direct access to the `KeyboardView`. You do, however, have to provide your own drawables for all six states in the linked platform drawable. So, 1.) Make those two `Key`s `android:isSticky="true"`. 2.) Copy the platform drawable XML. 3.) Make your drawables for each state, making the `btn_keyboard_key_normal_on` green. 4.) Set `android:keyBackground="@drawable/btn_keyboard_key"` on the `<KeyboardView>`. That's really all there is. You'll have to handle the one-at-a-time behavior in your code.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I added a drawable state for pressed. But how could I handle the one-at-a-time behaviour in my code? Please post a sample code? I updated the key listener code

Comment: I don't have time to put together a proper answer, at the moment, but here are some snippets from my simple test project I used to confirm my suggestions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A0wML-JPl2A_KuQPeflHUiVAtHTh-qta/view?usp=drivesdk.